# An inequality in Perelman's paper "Elements of Morse theory on Aleksandrov spaces"

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

I am trying to understand Perelman's paper "Elements of Morse theory on Aleksandrov spaces", St. Petersburg Math. J. 5 (1994), no. 1, 205–213. A version in Russian is [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/f0b412063e5c94ddf9500f1f5e274983/aa374.pdf).

Let $\Sigma^n$ be an $n$-dimensional Alexandrov space of curvature at least 1. Perelman denotes by $\mathrm{DER}(\Sigma)$ the set of sums of the form
$$
f(\xi)=-\sum_\alpha a_\alpha\cos|A_\alpha \xi|,
$$
where

- $a_\alpha\geq 0$,
- $\sum_\alpha a_\alpha \leq 1$,
- $A_\alpha\subset\Sigma$ is a compact subset and
- $|A_\alpha \xi|$ is the distance between a point $\xi$ and $A_\alpha$.

For $f,g\in \mathrm{DER}(\Sigma)$ where $f$ is as above and similarly $g(\xi)=-\sum_\beta b_\beta\cos|B_\beta \xi|$ he defines
$$
\langle f,g\rangle:=\sum_{\alpha,\beta}a_\alpha b_\beta \cos|A_\alpha B_\beta|.$$

Perelman claims on p. 237 that for any $f\in \mathrm{DER}(\Sigma)$ one has
$$
\langle f,f\rangle\geq \Big(\inf_{g\in \mathrm{DER}(\Sigma)}\langle f,g\rangle\Big)^2.$$

**I would be happy to have a proof of this claim.**